# ReactJS filter complex Json

Tags: json, reactjs, filter, treeview

[enter image description here][1]Please help me as I am struggling to get something to work. I have a JSON that represents a tree view in my app.

```
{
    name: 'Global',    toggled: true,    children: [
        {
            name: 'Region A', nodeid:  0,chosen: true,pushed: false,
            children: [
                { name: 'Town A', nodeid: 1, chosen: true, pushed: false,
                  children: [{
                    name : "child 1", pushed: false, chosen:false
                  }]
                },
                { name: 'Town B', nodeid: 2, chosen: false, pushed: false,
                  children: [{
                    name : "child 2", pushed: false, chosen: false
                  }]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

What I want to do is traverse through my JSON and only return the entries which have the chosen property as true.

I tried many things without success so far, would you guys be able to help me?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r61MO.jpg

```
   onPush(e){
      var chosennodes =  filters.filterTreeChosen(this.state.data);
      this.setState({selectednodes: chosennodes});
    }
```

Then the filter itself:

```
[Object.filter = (obj, predicate) =>
        Object.keys(obj)
            .filter( key => predicate(obj\[key\]) )
            .reduce( (res, key) => (res\[key\] = obj\[key\], res), {} );

export const isChosen = (chosen) =>{
    return chosen == true;
}

export const filterTreeChosen = (nodes) => {
    var filtered = Object.filter(nodes, node => node.chosen == true);
    console.log(filtered);
};][1]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAXZ7.jpg

Comment: None of those have `chosen: true`

Comment: chosen true is set programmatically... I edited the JSON for example's sake.

Comment: Can you post the code that is supposed to accomplish this? When you say "traverse through the JSON" it makes me think you are not parsing it into a JavaScript object.

Comment: Have you tried logging data to the console to confirm that your filter is working at all? I still don't see where you parse the JSON into JavaScript. You should post the code in which you actually try to use the filter. Can you please add it in code format for readability by editing your question itself?

Comment: If the node has `chosen: true` should filter return the whole node with all children?

Comment: @IvanBurnaev no, just the actual part where it has the true, no children for now.

Comment: @Smaft, please check the main post, I edited and added my current code.

Comment: Ivan's answer is the way to go. Just make sure you are parsing your JSON into a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out. I think it should apply to your task.

```js
const tree = {
    name: 'Global',    toggled: true,    children: [
        {
            name: 'Region A', nodeid:  0,chosen: true,pushed: false,
            children: [
                { name: 'Town A', nodeid: 1, chosen: true, pushed: false,
                  children: [{
                    name : "child 1", pushed: false, chosen:false
                  }]
                },
                { name: 'Town B', nodeid: 2, chosen: false, pushed: false,
                  children: [{
                    name : "child 2", pushed: false, chosen: false
                  }]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

function getChosenNodes (nodes) {
  let result = [];
  
  nodes.forEach(node => {
    if (node.chosen) {
      result = result.concat([node.nodeid]);
    }


    if (node.children) {
      result = result.concat(getChosenNodes(node.children));
    }
  })
  
  return result;
}

console.log(getChosenNodes([tree]))
```

I've returned only `nodeid` but you can change it as you need.

Comment: How is this going to perform if the tree has 10k or more nodes?

Comment: It depends on recursion level. Smaller recursion - faster function.